# Modal view opens in Master view of Splitview

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog

Currently, I am working on a new idea for an iOS app. This includes an iPhone and iPad version. The iPad version is using an Splitview with on the left the masterview with an table and on the right an detailview. This is working fine. But I want to make an 'Add' view wich will be an modal view who can be launched from an bar button in de right (master) view of the splitview.

When testing that, I came to the conclusion that the Modal view is only opening in the Master view, and not on the whole screen. I tried changes a few settings, such as 'Wants to be fullscreen', but nothing solved the problem.

Does someone now how to make the modal view use the whole view in place of the right(master) view of the split view?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite make sense to me because when I do [`presentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) (or use a modal segue) from a split view detail view, the new view will take up the whole screen by default. Are you doing any specification of the frame of the new view controller?

You can change the `presentViewController` behavior by setting [`modalPresentationStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle). For example, before you do your `presentViewController`, specify the `modalPresentationStyle`:

```
[self.destinationViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
```

If this doesn't work, then perhaps you can share your code that you use to present your modal view (e.g. plain old "modal" segue in storyboard? custom segue? using NIBs and calling `presentViewController` yourself? etc.), as well as your relevant `init` code for your destination view controller.